# Expand the for loop across n number of columns by making a function in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe `result` (provided in dput) where I have A,C,G,T, N and X columns. These letters A,C,G,T, N and X are also present in column ALT1 through ALTn. In this particular example, I have ALT columns ranging from ALT1 to ALT2 only, but there are instances where it could range upto ALTn. Now, this is what I want to do- I would like to match the letters in ALT1, ALT2..ALTn with the letters in columns A,C,G,T, N and X (basically the colnames) and extract the corresponding numerical values in those columns pasting along with the letters in REF column and its corresponding numerical value in A,C,G,T, N and X columns. I have written this for loop (my loop) which simply does this job for column ALT2 and stores the result in final2. I wan to make a function with this loop so than this can be expanded to all the columns ultimately giving me the results in the form of final1, final2, final3..finaln (please see the expected result for final1). I then want the final1 through finaln pasted together.  How do I get this done in R?

dput (`result`):

```
structure(list(start = c("chr1:101544447", "chr1:102053031", 
"chr1:102778767", "chr1:102789831", "chr1:102989480", "chr1:103310574", 
"chr1:103870326"), A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA), C = c(NA, 
34L, 24L, NA, NA, 22L, 12L), G = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), T = c(53L, NA, NA, 30L, 12L, NA, NA), N = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), X. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X..1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), end = c(101544447L, 102053031L, 102778767L, 
102789831L, 102989480L, 103310574L, 103870326L), REF = c("A", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), ALT = c("T", "G", "T", "T", "T", 
"A", "A"), ALT1 = c("T", "G", "T", "T", "T", "A", "A"), ALT2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), TYPE = c("snp", "snp", "snp", "snp", 
"snp", "snp", "snp")), .Names = c("start", "A", "C", "G", "T", 
"N", "X.", "X..1", "end", "REF", "ALT", "ALT1", "ALT2", "TYPE"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

> my loop

```
final1 <- {}
    i <- 1

    for(i in 1:nrow(result)){
      final1[i] = paste(paste(result$chr[i], result$start[i], result$end[i],sep=":"),"-", 
                       result$REF[i],"(",result[,(as.character(result$REF[i]))][i],")",",", result$ALT1[i],
                       "(",result[,(as.character(result$ALT1[i]))][i][!is.na(result[,(as.character(result$ALT1[i]))][i])],")",sep="")

    }

    final1
```

Expected output (only for ALT1 column):

```
> final1
[1] ":chr1:101544447:101544447-A(NA),T(53)" ":chr1:102053031:102053031-C(34),G()"   ":chr1:102778767:102778767-C(24),T()"  
[4] ":chr1:102789831:102789831-C(NA),T(30)" ":chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),T(12)" ":chr1:103310574:103310574-C(22),A(2)" 
[7] ":chr1:103870326:103870326-C(12),A()"
```

Comment: Your `REF` references reflect the `NA`, but the `ALT1` referenced column shows blanks for `NA`s. Is this an intentional inconsistency?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand it first what you meant. It can be NA or can be left blank, it is not that important.

Comment: Your example doesn't really make sense, since your `ALT2` column is all `NA`s ... you haven't indicated how non-existent columns should be handled. Also, might I also suggest that in the spirit of [minimal working examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please do not clutter the question with unnecessary columns. You could probably get the desired help with 9 columns instead of 14. As it stands (with `ALT2` unusable), we'll need to make many assumptions to do anything.

Comment: In this ALT2 column there are nucleotides(A,C,T and G) but no coverage (numerical values in the A,C,G,T, N and X  columns). I want to make a function so that if ALT2 column itself is missing, it automatically stops the loop at ALT1 or if there is ALT3 or ALT1000 , I want to extend that function to the maximum numbers of ALTn columns. Sorry if it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Not confusing, just neither stated in the question nor obvious. You are still not clear, however: if there is an `NA` in `ALT2` *and* there is an `ALT3`, what should happen?

Comment: I have the ALT2 in other rows, but not in the rows I have provided. So it's either present or not present. Thank you very much for working on it. I will give it a try on the answer you have provided.

Comment: I have several data and some data have columns upto  ALT2 only some have upto ALT15. So I wanted to make a function that would work on all types of data.

Comment: You need to state that in your original question, that was not obvious nor even implied. You will run into errors with my answer below, so you will need to add a check with `is.na` and do something meaningful when you hit `NA`s.

Comment: Could you please kindly make that changes in the answer you have provided? I don't want to mess up everything. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your data, I've modified it slightly to provide an `ALT2` column that's actually usable (i.e., not all `NA`s):

```
## result, as defined above
set.seed(42)
result$ALT2 <- sample(c('A','C','G','T'), size=nrow(result), replace=TRUE)
result
##            start  A  C  G  T  N X. X..1       end REF ALT ALT1 ALT2 TYPE
## 1 chr1:101544447 NA NA NA 53 NA NA   NA 101544447   A   T    T    T  snp
## 2 chr1:102053031 NA 34 NA NA NA NA   NA 102053031   C   G    G    T  snp
## 3 chr1:102778767 NA 24 NA NA NA NA   NA 102778767   C   T    T    C  snp
## 4 chr1:102789831 NA NA NA 30 NA NA   NA 102789831   C   T    T    T  snp
## 5 chr1:102989480 NA NA NA 12 NA NA   NA 102989480   C   T    T    G  snp
## 6 chr1:103310574  2 22 NA NA NA NA   NA 103310574   C   A    A    G  snp
## 7 chr1:103870326 NA 12 NA NA NA NA   NA 103870326   C   A    A    G  snp
```

From here, I start by finding all of the desired `ALT` columns:

```
alts <- colnames(result)[grepl('ALT[0-9]+', colnames(result))]
alts
## [1] "ALT1" "ALT2"
```

Next, the code to do all `ALT`s in one fell swoop, regardless of the number of desired columns. It's a bit more verbose than is strictly required, but it helps see how things are broken down component-wise.

```
ret <- t(sapply(1:nrow(result), function(r) {
    dat <- result[r,]
    part1 <- paste(c('', dat[,c('start','end')]), collapse=':')
    part2 <- sprintf('%s(%s)', dat$REF, dat[ dat$REF ])
    part3 <- sapply(alts, function(alt) sprintf('%s(%s)', dat[[alt]], dat[ dat[[alt]] ]) )
    part23 <- paste(part2, part3, sep=',')
    paste(part1, part23, sep='-')
}))
colnames(ret) <- alts
ret
##      ALT1                                    ALT2                                   
## [1,] ":chr1:101544447:101544447-A(NA),T(53)" ":chr1:101544447:101544447-A(NA),T(53)"
## [2,] ":chr1:102053031:102053031-C(34),G(NA)" ":chr1:102053031:102053031-C(34),T(NA)"
## [3,] ":chr1:102778767:102778767-C(24),T(NA)" ":chr1:102778767:102778767-C(24),C(24)"
## [4,] ":chr1:102789831:102789831-C(NA),T(30)" ":chr1:102789831:102789831-C(NA),T(30)"
## [5,] ":chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),T(12)" ":chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),G(NA)"
## [6,] ":chr1:103310574:103310574-C(22),A(2)"  ":chr1:103310574:103310574-C(22),G(NA)"
## [7,] ":chr1:103870326:103870326-C(12),A(NA)" ":chr1:103870326:103870326-C(12),G(NA)"
```

Explanation:

- the outer `t(sapply(...))` is used to iterate over each row of the data.frame. The `t(...)` is necessary since it will otherwise be rotated from what you might expect.
- `part1` and `part2` both create a single string for the row. Since each of the `ALT`s created in a row will have these components in common, it's only necessary to create them once each.
- `part3` creates as many strings as there are `ALT`s.
- `part23` merely merges the one `part2` with each of the `part3`s.

It might be informative to set `r <- 1` on the console and step through this process manually, inspecting variables as they are being created.

Finally, you said you wanted (for a reason that eludes me) to combine each of the strings for the `ALT`s into a single string. You can do that with:

```
apply(ret, 1, paste, collapse='')
## [1] ":chr1:101544447:101544447-A(NA),T(53):chr1:101544447:101544447-A(NA),T(53)"
## [2] ":chr1:102053031:102053031-C(34),G(NA):chr1:102053031:102053031-C(34),T(NA)"
## [3] ":chr1:102778767:102778767-C(24),T(NA):chr1:102778767:102778767-C(24),C(24)"
## [4] ":chr1:102789831:102789831-C(NA),T(30):chr1:102789831:102789831-C(NA),T(30)"
## [5] ":chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),T(12):chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),G(NA)"
## [6] ":chr1:103310574:103310574-C(22),A(2):chr1:103310574:103310574-C(22),G(NA)" 
## [7] ":chr1:103870326:103870326-C(12),A(NA):chr1:103870326:103870326-C(12),G(NA)"
```

BTW: I'm not certain why you placed a leading colon before the first `chr1:...`. If it was in anticipation of this final merge, it can be better achieved by changing one line in the `sapply` code to:

```
part1 <- paste(dat[,c('start','end')], collapse=':')
```

and the final line to:

```
apply(ret, 1, paste, collapse=':')
```

But perhaps you have a reason not clear to me.

Cheers!

**Edit**: it should be trivial to encapsulate this in a function:

```
func <- function(result) {
    alts <- ...
    ret <- t(sapply(...
    colnames(ret) <- alts
    apply(ret, 1, paste, collapse='')
}
func(result)
```

**Edit #2**: with the growing list of requirements, I feel like I'm in a spiral-development government contract ;-)

Going back to the unadulterated data (unmodified `ALT2`), I modified *one* of the `ALT2` in order to test to see if this code does what I'm inferring is intended:

```
result$ALT2[5] <- 'A'
```

... and now the modified code, all-in-one:

```
ret <- sapply(1:nrow(result), function(r) {
    dat <- result[r,]
    part1 <- paste(c('', dat[,c('start','end')]), collapse=':')
    part2 <- sprintf('%s(%s)', dat$REF, dat[ dat$REF ])
    part3 <- unlist(sapply(alts, function(alt) {
        if (is.na(dat[[alt]])) NULL
        else sprintf('%s(%s)', dat[[alt]], dat[ dat[[alt]] ])
    }))
    part23 <- paste(part2, part3, sep=',')
    part123 <- paste(part1, part23, sep='-', collapse='')
})
ret
## [1] ":chr1:101544447:101544447-A(NA),T(53)"                                     
## [2] ":chr1:102053031:102053031-C(34),G(NA)"                                     
## [3] ":chr1:102778767:102778767-C(24),T(NA)"                                     
## [4] ":chr1:102789831:102789831-C(NA),T(30)"                                     
## [5] ":chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),T(12):chr1:102989480:102989480-C(NA),A(NA)"
## [6] ":chr1:103310574:103310574-C(22),A(2)"                                      
## [7] ":chr1:103870326:103870326-C(12),A(NA)"
```

Comment: Provide more representative data. Provide the error message. Provide code you tried where it differs from what has been provided. I cannot read your mind nor your *R* terminal. My code works without error given what you have provided so far (as demonstrated). (The above should be provided as *additions* to your question, since adding them to comments is heinous to follow.)

Comment: Clearly I made a mistake here with my data. It now worked fine! Sorry again man!